# How to make Microsoft JVM work on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, java, jvm

I am struggling with the following problem. I cannot install [MS JVM 3810](http://www.softwarepatch.com/windows/javavm.html) properly on Windows 7. When I start Interner Explorer 8 without starting any java 1.1 programs choosing Java custom settings under Internet options causes the crash of the browser.

I have some Java 1.1 programs that work well in Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP after the installation of MS JVM 3810. I know that it is not advised to use this old JVM but it is not a short-term option to port the programs in newer Java since it contains 3rd party components. Complete rewrite is a long-term plan.

Strangely `jview` and `appletviewer` (`jview /a`) works from a console so the MS JVM 3810 is not completely busted just IE 8 does not like it. The problem with the appletviewer is that it cannot connect to the server even if both signed and unsigned content in Java custom settings have been set to Enable all. (Since Java custom settings was unreachable due to the crash the modifications - including My computer - were performed through the registry and pre-checked to behave correctly on Windows XP and Internet Explorer 8.)
If jview was working then I could at least think of a workaround.

Is there a way to configure MS JVM or jview properly on Windows 7?

Another options would be:

- Checking Internet Explorer 9 Beta.
- Using virtualbox and Windows XP older IE in it.
- Delaying Windows 7 upgrade.
- ...

**Update**

Finally we have modified all the programs to work parallelly as applet and application as well.

This way the programs can still be used from browser on older Windows versions. On Windows 7 the applications are started from the desktop. Installation to all user machine can easily be solved since they already have a large common application drive.
The code update is fortunately only a few lines of modification: including a main method in the applet class.
Furthermore instead of the starting html page a bat file is used to set the classpath before the startup with jview.

Comment: Unless the code has check for the JVM it is running on, it should run on the newer JVMs.  I have run applets designed for Java 1.1 on all veersions up to 1.5.

Comment: Certain 1.1 codes may run on 1.5 but we have tried it years ago and there were incompatibilities: e.g. calling select(-1) on an awt combo box were throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Am I wrong in thinking that the latest Oracle JVM will run Java 1.1 bytecode?

Have you tried this? What errors did you get?

Does the app or libraries rely on MS extensions?

A [Microsoft forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/90114ac3-5468-4491-829c-4f98bf8be1b5) suggests some workarounds.

---

If you can't fix the problems when running the unsupported and obsolete MSJVM under Windows 7, the only way to run the application is to do so under an older Windows operating system, perhaps in a Virtual-PC under Windows-7.

Microsoft have a [MSJVM transition guide](http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/Interoperability/Java/Default.aspx) which includes a MSJVM Diagnostic tool and tools to translate J++ to C#.

I don't think you can easily overcome the fundamental issue that Microsoft dropped support for MSJVM.

Comment: Yes, I have tried JDK 1.5 and 1.6 but with no luck. I can move on with porting my codes to JDK 1.5 but based on previous experiences it is a complex task. First of all, I would like to know if sticking to Java 1.1 and MS JVM is possible.

Comment: See the answer in the Microsoft Forum referred to above - it describes how to make MS JVM work under Windows 7

Comment: Where does it describe? It is a solution to a specific problem different from ours. Moreover I do not think any suggestions on that Microsoft forum could solve our problems.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help you.

Comment: Yep, these MS extensions to Java was a big part of why Sun sued. If your code depends on them you should consider porting to J# instead.

Answer (score 0):

JVM 3810 is only an upgrade to an earlier version.  You need to install sone earlier vers like JVM 3805, and then install 3810 on top of it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JVM on Windows 7 and IE8/IE7 by disabling DEP. Just type the following into an elevated command prompt:

```
bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff
```

and restart the computer, before enabling JVM settings in Internet Options.

The statement has to be executed at command line after opening cmd.exe as Administrator by 
right-clicking on cmd.exe in Windows\System32 and selecting "Run as Administartor".

It works, I am using it, but I cannot find a solution for the same on IE9 + Windows 7.

Comment: -1 Disabling DEP globally is a bad idea.